# complex lmer mixed model specification

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I am attempting to fit a linear mixed-effect model in R using `lme4` that is quite a bit more complex than any example I've seen in forums or in textbooks. I am having trouble finding the correct code for the random effects in particular. I have two fixed factors (parental environment and germination treatment) and random factor (genetic line); I want to test all 2 and 3-way interactions between these factors. I have two additional fixed factors that I want to test without interactions (provisioning and block). I want to specify random intercepts and slopes for genetic line, but I am not sure how to do this. The dependent variable is biomass.

Is this model specification correct?:

```
fullmod <- lmer(biomass ~ parental.environment* germination.treatment*
   (1+parental.environment*germination.treatment|genetic.line)
                + provisioning + block, biomass.data)
```

I am also interested in testing the significance of the 3-way interaction parental environment x germination treatment x genetic line by comparing the fit of the reduced model to the full model. What would be the correct model specification for the full model minus this 3-way interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly right.

The main effects of the fixed terms plus their interaction is/are represented as

```
1+parental.environment* germination.treatment
```

Interactions between random and fixed factors are coded as variation of the fixed effects across levels of the random effects grouping variables, like so:

```
(1+parental.environment* germination.treatment|genetic.line)
```

As with all R model formulae, you can choose to include or not include the intercept term explicitly.

The only confusion on your part is that these terms are combined with `+` rather than `*`,

```
fullmod <- lmer(biomass ~ parental.environment* germination.treatment +
   (1+parental.environment*germination.treatment|genetic.line) +
                provisioning + block, biomass.data)
```

> I am also interested in testing the significance of the 3-way interaction parental environment x germination treatment x genetic line by comparing the fit of the reduced model to the full model.

The reduced model would be

```
biomass ~ parental.environment* germination.treatment +
       (1+parental.environment+germination.treatment|genetic.line) +
                    provisioning + block
```

Two notes (1) if there are $m$ levels of parental environment and $n$ levels of germination treatment, you will be fitting an $mn \times mn$ variance-covariance matrix (with $mn(mn+1)/2$ parameters), so you'd better have enough genetic lines to make that practical; (2) significance tests of variance components are a little tricky (the $p$-values from a naive likelihood ratio test are typically conservative by a factor of about 2; see Pinheiro and Bates 2000).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would appreciate some clarification. When you say that my only confusion is "these terms are combined with + rather than *", I took you to mean that I should use + to combine parental environment and germination treatment in the random effects specification of the full model. If so, I do not see a difference between the full model and the reduced model that you suggested. Am I correct in my interpretation, and if so, what is the correct reduced model?

Comment: the character at the end of the first line of your formula, connecting the fixed- and random-effects parts of the formula, is a `*`; it should be `+` instead.  I would expect that if you entered the formula exactly as shown in your question it would generate some interesting error messages.